# Python: Nested dictionary with arbitrary number of levels

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd appreciate help for this apparently simple task: write a function that will take a tuple and return a nested dictionary, with each successive value in the tuple being a key in a successively deeper 'layer' of the dictionary.
The ultimate 'value' at the bottom of the rainbow is specified (say 10, in the following example).

So from the tuple `('cat', 'dog', 'bone')`, I'm aiming to have as an output:

```
{'cat':{'dog':{'bone':10}}}
```

and to do this for tuples of arbitrary length.

Comment: In turn, we would appreciate a sample of your code, to see at least an attempt to solve the problem from your part ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is that 'ultimate value' specified exactly?

In the code below it is specified by named argument:

```
def nested_dict(tuple, value=10):
    if len(tuple) is 1:
        return { tuple[0] : value }
    return { tuple[0] : nested_dict(tuple[1:], value=value) }
```

Comment: don't use `is` to compare `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = ('cat','dog','bone')
answer = {}
temp = answer
for key in t[:-1]:
    if key not in temp:
        temp[key] = {}
    temp = temp[key]
temp[t[-1]] = 10
```

Output:

```
In [21]: answer
Out[21]: {'cat': {'dog': {'bone': 10}}}
```

Comment: Can also use: `reduce(lambda a, b: a.setdefault(b, {}), t[:-1], answer)[t[-1]] = 10`

Answer (score 0):

My attempt as well:

```
>>> t = ('cat', 'dog', 'bone')
>>> last = {t[-1]: 10}
>>> for e in t[1::-1]:
...     last = {e: last}
... 
>>> last
{'cat': {'dog': {'bone': 10}}}
```